# How to fix Error y[outlier.qs, ] : incorrect number of dimensions when coloring outliers

Tags: r, plot, colors, outliers

My goal is to the univariate approach for outlier detection using the plot and points functions. DMwR package being used.

The example code given in the assignment is:

```
x <- data.frame(1:100, x)
plot(x, main = "x outlier", col = "darkgreen")
points(x[outlier.x, ], col= 'red', pch = 'x', cex = 1.5)
```

Address missing values:

```
clean.qs <- na.omit(sales$quantitySold)
```

Summarize data:

```
summary(clean.qs)
   #Min.  1st Qu.  Median  Mean   3rd Qu.    Max. 
   #1005    1345    2675   14617    8680   4642955
```

For quantitySold variable

```
plot(clean.qs, main='Quantity Sold', col='darkgreen')
qs.out <- boxplot.stats(clean.qs)$out
```

Find the index for outliers:

```
outlier.qs <- which(clean.qs %in% qs.out)
```

Attempt 1:

```
plot(clean.qs, main='Quantity Sold', col='darkgreen')
points(clean.qs[outlier.qs, ], col='red', pch='x', cex=1.5)
```

Attempt 2:

```
set.seed(3147)
x <- data.frame(1:387304, clean.qs)
plot(clean.qs, main='Quantity Sold', col='darkgreen')
points(clean.qs[outlier.qs, ], col='red', pch='x', cex=1.5)
```

This code should produce a plot with dark green circles for non-outliers and adds red x's on top the green circles for outliers.

The plot function runs successfully, however this error arises during the points function:  "Error in clean.qs[outlier.qs, ] : incorrect number of dimensions".

Comment: In the headline of my question, please read "y[outlier.sda, ]" to be "y[outlier.qs, ]".  Thank you.

Comment: remove the comma after outlier.qs

Comment: Richard Huff, there's no need to put in a comment what you can do directly: just [edit this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56382256/edit) and fix the title yourself. Comments can be easily skipped or even hidden (if there are a lot of comments), so it's best to keep the question as relevant/correct as possible.

Comment: r2evans: thank you. I see the edit button now and updated the question.

Comment: Wave: removing the comma did produce a chart. I think there may be a second adjustment needed, because quantitySold is now on the y-axis and the marked data points don't look like outliers (they are the left-most fifth of the data).